# can radiation burst provide electrical devices malfunction?

Tags: electromagnetism, radiation

I wonder if a radiation burst create an electrial device malfunction or desactivation.

Can radiation create electromagnetic impulse ?

Comment: please specify what you mean by radiation

Answer (score 0):

It is well-known that intense bursts of electromagnetic radiation in the radio frequency range can destroy electronic equipment, an effect commonly called *EMP* or Electro Magnetic Pulse. Electronic devices intended for use on the battlefield during nuclear war must be very carefully designed and shielded to prevent them from being ruined when an atomic or nuclear weapon is exploded and releases an EMP, even if the distance between the explosion and the device is of order ~hundreds of miles (depending on things like the altitude of the explosion and its size).